# find all related words from a root word [NLP python]

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

Is it possible to find all the related words from a root word (Kind of like a reverse stemming).
For example, study -> [study , studies, studying, studied]

Comment: I just found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104148/11653190). If there are any other solutions, please do answer.

Answer (score 0):

Snowball is a small string processing language designed for creating stemming algorithms for use in Information Retrieval. This site describes Snowball, and presents several useful stemmers which have been implemented using it.

source: https://snowballstem.org/

To download the module : https://pypi.org/project/snowballstemmer/